# Proving that $ f $ has an absolute minimum in a given closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have the following problem with a solution that I already did. I would just like to see other possibly simpler and / or shorter solutions. Let $ f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $f(x)=g(x)+\lambda x^{2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ($\lambda>0$), where $g$ is continue and non negative in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that there exists $r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ f $ reaches an absolute minimum in $ r $ and $|r|\leqslant \sqrt{\frac{g(0)}{\lambda}}$.

**My solution**

Consider the interval $I$ defined by: $$I=\left[-\sqrt{\frac{g(0)}{\lambda}},\sqrt{\frac{g(0)}{\lambda}} \right]$$

Denote by $f|_{I}:I\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the restriction of $f$ to $I$. This function is continue in $I$, since $f$ is continue. Since $I$ is a bounded and closed interval, by Weierstrass $f|_{I}$ reaches an absolute minimum in $I$, i.e., there exists $r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_{I}(x)\geqslant f|_{I}(r)$ for all $x\in I$. We will prove that $r$ satisfies the conditions. By definition, $|r|\leqslant \sqrt{\frac{g(0)}{\lambda}}$. Its enough to see then that $r$ is an absolute minimum of $f$. For this, we will show that $f(x)\geqslant f(r)$, being $x\in \mathbb{R}$, analyzing two cases:

**Case 1:** $x\in I$. Then, $f(x)=f|_{I}(x)\geqslant f|_{I}(r)=f(r)$.

**Case 2:** $x\notin I$. Then, $\lambda x^{2}>g(0)$. Further, $0\in I$, hence $f|_{I}(r)\leqslant f|_{I}(0)$. Consequently: $$f(x)=g(x)+\lambda x^{2}\geqslant \lambda x^{2}>g(0)=f(0)=f|_{I}(0)\geqslant f|_{I}(r)=f(r)$$

This ends the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the proof is correct and easiest possible (up to a few words). The function is not **continue**, but **continuous** .

Comment: Thank you very much, my English fails, I appreciate it

Comment: OK, you have better English than I when I arrived to the US.